# How to take a screenshot in XCUITest during press&hold?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcuitest, snapshot-testing

I need to take a screenshot in the middle of zoom/pan/rotate, i.e. I expect some code like this:

```
element.startPressAndHold(.twoTouches)
// at this point my app renders differently, so I capture a screenshot
// for snapshot testing
let shot = element.screenshot()
element.stopPressAndHold()
```

`XCUIElement` in fact has something similar for keys:

```
XCUIElement.perform(withKeyModifiers: .command) {
    let shot = element.screenshot()
}
```

but I can not find something similar for mouse/touches/gestures.

Is there a trick to achieve this?

Comment: `press(forDuration:)` is all there is and as you’re finding, you won’t be able to take a screenshot until after that has completed. If there is a solution it’d be spawning that command in a separate thread from the main one, but I don’t know how to do that off the top of my head and XCUITest might not handle multiple threads of execution. You’d need to account for the timer in your main thread as well.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62082625/2533443